# Unity 4.5 is crashing

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, crash-reports

I had Unity 4.5 and it worked fine, then I upgraded to 4.6 (to check what is different). But when I re-installed the 4.5 version, Unity started to crash on startup! It looks like Unity is uploading, but the IDE is not shown and then it crashes.
I uninstalled all the Unity versions I had and re-install the 4.5 version, but it also crashes. Is there something else that you can advise?

Comment: it might crash, because it tries to open your unity project, that is already upgraded to Unity 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the problem was that one of the scene included a component of Unity 4.6 - the UI. I installed unity 4.6 - deleted this component and then installed unity 4.5 and now it works :)